# Mapping with InstantObjects

Tags: delphi, mapping, instantobjects

I installed InstantObjects for Delphi today, studied sample application. Everything seems to work clear and fine. Just one question so far - is it possible to map InstantObjects classes to existing database tables instead of creating a new database?

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's changed recently, due to it's architecture, InstantObjects requires total control over the database which makes using it against a legacy database somewhat difficult. Your best bet, if you want to carry on using IO would be to write some kind of import routine from your legacy database and map the field values onto your IO Objects, then save them across to the main IO persistence layer. You might get some more information by posting posting on the Instant Objects newsgroups.

Alternatively, there are other OPFs (e.g. tiOPF), which work better with legacy databases.